# How to share an image which is in GridView android?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to share the image which is in grid view. When I long press the image in grid view , I want the particular image to share. I tried sending "texts" and I am able to send it but , when I try sending image, it is throwing null pointer exception. I have checked my code but I don't know where I missed it .

Here is my code,

```
private GridView grid;
Context context;

private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
private int thumb[] = {
        R.drawable.tcdhspecs, R.drawable.talspec, R.drawable.tgpspecs, R.drawable.ttospecs, R.drawable.tglspecs, R.drawable.thdspec};
private ImageButton expandedImageView;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

private int mShortAnimationDuration;
private int j = 0;
String[] web = {

        "VETHA TCDH",
        "VETHA TAL",
        "VETHA TGP",
        "VETHA TTO",


};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_pinch_vetha, container, false);

    Customgrid_pinch_vetha adapter = new Customgrid_pinch_vetha(getContext(), web, thumb);

    grid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    expandedImageView = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (100), 100));
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(expandedImageView.getLayoutParams());
    marginParams.setMargins((int) (100 / 1.5), 0, 0, 0);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
    expandedImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

  System.out.println(thumb[pos]);

        }
    });

          android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    registerForContextMenu(grid);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();             
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share_fav:
  BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) expandedImageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                    "Share image using"));


        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}
}
```

And my log ..

```
  12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication  E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at   app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication.SpecTabsVetha.onContextItemSelected(SpecTabsVetha.java:201)
 12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:2085)
 12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2132)
12-07 17:25:58.049 11486-11486/app.dme.anusha.dmeapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentController.java:308)
```

This is my code. When I try sending image which is in grid view, it throws out null pointer exception. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your logs here.

Comment: I have updated it . Please check @EricB.

Comment: Which is your line no. `201`?

Comment: The documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) states that, `bm.getBitmap();` may return `null`. So check whether `mysharebmp` is not null.

Comment: I checked it . The exception is gone but on clicking share, nothing happens @EricB.

Comment: Try logging the uri and see what value does it have.

Comment: How to log the uri ? Could you give me an example ? @EricB.

Comment: I assume there is no app to create the called intent. try adding set type as image/jpeg . Check if the url is not null..

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work @DhinakaranThennarasu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the image through `expandedImageView.getDrawable()`, set the path of the image in `setTag()`, and try to access the image.

The image could be big or small. `expandedImageView.getDrawable()` can give you null value.